# Drupal 7 large files from private file system not fully downloading

Tags: 7, files

Files from private system are not fully downloading. When I download the file of 20MB or less it is downloaded perfectly.

Files more than 20MB are not fully downloaded. For example after downloading 60MB file it shows only 35MB  and cannot open then file. But browser shows download is success and there error in dblog.

**NOTE:**
1. Small files are downloaded perfectly
2. No error or warning occurs in dblog
3. Browser showing download is success

Comment: Probably misconfigured headers being sent by your server. Almost impossible to guess what that might be from here

Comment: 1. check your internet connection
2. are you using shared hosting? check with hosting provider
3. open the file in textpad or notepad++ and see the last lines, is there any error?

Comment: I cannot open the file and it is zip file @NikunjKotecha

Comment: hi Harsha, you can open any file with textpad in windows or textwrangler in mac, thought it might not be readable. At times if there is some error and apache finishes download in between it also sends some error and that might be readable at the end of the file.